# How to pick out first letter from words in dot-separated string

Tags: python

How do I pick out the letters in a string like: `"first.last"`.

I want to pick out the `f` in first, and the `l` in last.

But I need to make it where when someone inputs something like `"quartz.block"` I need to get the `'q'` and `'b'`.

Does anyone have any ideas how?

Comment: `[w[0] for w in string.split(".")]`?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For help with implementing something, we expect you to attempt it yourself first. Please read [ask]. See also: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) (even if this isn't a homework question, there's still some good advice here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
word = "quartz.block"
first_last = f"{word[0]}{word[word.index('.') + 1]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `split(".")` function. Separate the words where dot (.) is present and print the first letter of the separated words. Your code:

```
string = input("Enter= ")
words = string.split(".")
for word in words:
    print(word[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Shakespeare iterator solution:

```
it = iter('quartz.block')
print([c for c in it
       if '.' in it
       or '.' not in it])
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7NEwVYhsyS1SEO9sDSxqKRKLyknPzlbXZOroCgzr0QjOlkhLb9IIVkhMw@ojEsBAjLTFNT11FHFgKpAYnn5JRDxWM3//wE)):

```
['q', 'b']
```